# Classifier is giving different results every time it is trained even though the training and test data is the same

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

The training and test data are pickled and loaded. But the results (accuracy and f-measure) seem to vary every time even though the classifier is trained with the same training data and tested with the same test data. How is this happening? The classifier I'm referring to is Extreme Learning Machine.

Comment: could you tell us more about your classifier ?

Comment: The classifier I'm using is Extreme Learning Machine. One guess is that this might be happening due to the random weights assigned every time it is trained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the classification algorithm you chose. If you chose something like random forests, each time a new model would be learnt, so such an observation is possible.

Comment: Is trial and error the only way to find the optimal model for such classifiers?

Comment: people generally do 5-fold or 10-fold cross validation and then chose the model with the best accuracy

Answer (score 0):

How different are the weights of the output? Do you get different parameters?

Bear in mind many algorithms start with different random seeds, which make them behave different for different sets of experiments.

How different are the outputs? Are they wildly different? If that is the case, perhaps you need to let it run longer.

As someone said, you have to use cross validation to find the best set of parameters and to do that you need to rotate your training and dataset.

Comment: The outputs are fairly wild.I guess ill run it as many times as my available resources and time allow. Im able to get a fair idea of the range of output with 10 runs.

Comment: How much data do you have? Too little data can also be an issue

Comment: I have around 10k records for training and around 5k for testing.